# What can I do to let the typescript type system know the type of the return value？

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types, factory-pattern

I am new to typescript, I am trying to migrate so code from js to ts while reading the ts HandBook.

Here is the relationship between each level developer and user:

lib developer -> `ProductProvider` ->
product developer -> `Product` ->
product user -> `robot`

It seems going well, except I have no idea how to tel typescript the type of the robot, which is the type of assembler function return value, also the type of Product function return value.

```
interface Injection {
    [index: string]: string
}

interface Component {
    id: string,
    install: (injection: Injection) => void
}

interface InitOptions {
    id: string,
    screenType: string,
    SoC: string,
    components: Component[],
}

type Assembler = (injection: object, options: object) => unknown;

type ProductProvider = (initOptions: InitOptions, assembler: Assembler) => (options: object) => ReturnType<typeof assembler>

function ProductProvider(initOptions: InitOptions, assembler: Assembler): (options: object) => ReturnType<typeof assembler> {
    //some work to init
    const installedInjection: Injection = {};
    initOptions.components.forEach((component => component.install(installedInjection)));
    
    return function Product(startOption: object): ReturnType<typeof assembler> {
        return assembler(installedInjection, startOption);
    }
}

export default ProductProvider;

const assembler: Assembler = (injection: object, options: object) => ({ injection, options });

const Product = ProductProvider({
    id: 'XMC9E8DCO5EXEU',
    screenType: 'LCD',
    SoC: 'RX-78',
    components: [{
        id: 'component1',
        install(injection) {
            //some work
            const content = 'whatever';
            injection[this.id] = content;
        } 
    }]
 }, assembler);

const robot = Product({ battery: 'A' });
```

In type `Assembler`, because the user of `ProductProvider` is freedom on how to assemble, so I think the type of function will return unknown.

But in fact, the Product developer know that the assemble parameter passed to ProductProvider, it return a value, and it type is object.

And other Product developers may also return another Interface or Type.

What can I do to let the typescript type system know the type of the return value? And then we can enjoy intellisense.

XD

Answer (score 0):

```
type Assembler<T> = (injection: object, options: object) => T;

type ProductProvider<T> = (initOptions: InitOptions, assembler: Assembler<T>) => (options: object) => T;
```

done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9GaF.png)